# JS box auto closes, perhaps a directory rewrite issue?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, url-rewriting

When trying to create a new campaign inside fatfreecrm or anything that triggers the same similar link it force closes the box again after 1-2 seconds.

I just installed FFCRM according to instructions so I do not know what the issue could be.

I am running fatfreecrm from a subdir on apache2.
The main dir has wordpress installed and rewrite engine enabled.

I noticed the addressbar does not show the full path when clicking on a link (see video).

Could it have something to do with my rewrite? I turned it off for this directory by adding

```
RackBaseURI /ffcrm
RailsEnv development
<Directory /home/petralian.com/public_html/ffcrm>
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine Off
</Directory>
```

to my directives.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the app to its own subdirectory and taking it off cloudflare fixed this issue. It had something to do with:

Error: "throw $continue" is deprecated, use "return" instead
in cloudflare.min.js (line 37)